# Passing arguments by reference Java

Tags: java, reference, arguments, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I am aware that there exists the 'out' keyword in C# for passing arguments by reference in a method. Does there exist an equivalent of the 'out' keyword in Java (for passing arguments by reference)?

Comment: java is always *pass by value*. *passing by reference* is nothing in java. More : [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1)

Comment: no java doesn't have such feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent in Java is to use an object to hold the reference so it can be returned. This is relatively ugly and best avoided but if you want a one for one translation you can do something like.

```
 ReturnValue method(out int arg, out String x);
```

translates to

```
 int[] argRef = { arg };
 String[] xRef = { x };
 // call to
 ReturnValue method(int[] argRef, String[] xRef);

 arg = argRef[0];
 x = xRef[0];
```

Comment: "Ugly" is not an engineering term, but nonetheless, why would you call it that? I shouldn't question emotions, I know, but I got curious. Holder objects are ubiquitous and useful. Some might find Java's uncomplicated approach lovely. Or was it that you showed arrays as the holders rather than a proper holder object that you deemed "ugly"? I would agree that the use of arrays is less idiomatic and direct than the use of a holder type.

Answer (score 0):

No there does not exist something like this in Java as far as I know.

However there are wrapper classes available for most types like Integer which you may use as parameter. Then you have objects you work with.